# Search records in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to select record that a tag contains .pdf in href.

I created a query :

```
Select * from tablename where coulmnname like '%<a href=%pdf%'
```

But it show all record like some record have .pdf enclose embed & iframe etc

```
<embed href="google.com/.pdf">
<iframe href="google.com/.pdf">
<a href="google.com/.pdf">
```

i want only record enclosed in a tag

```
<a href="google.com/.pdf">
```

Comment: Yes but .pdf enclose by embed or iframe as well, So only search those record which enclose with a tag

Comment: Edit your question and explain better your requirement

Comment: Are you saving <a href="google.com/.pdf"> as a single value in a column? And you are wanting to pull all records that have a .pdf in the <a href> tag?